# SQL splitting a column into 3 different columns with multiple seperators

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, substring

I have the column below which contains data as shown

```
|DeliveryComment          |   
|-------------------------|    
|[1 * B018]               |  
|GARAGE                   |  
|BACK GARDEN. [124 * B002]|   
|[1 * B018]               |  
|                         |  
|[124 * B002]             |   
|[1 * B018]               |  
|                         |    
|[124 * B002]             |
```

I'd like to split this data into three columns displayed as below.

```
|ColA       |ColB|ColC|  
|-----------|----|----|     
|           |1   |B018|   
|GARAGE     |    |    |   
|BACK GARDEN|124 |B002|  
|           |1   |B018|    
|           |    |    |    
|           |124 |B002|   
|           |1   |B018|  
|           |    |    |      
|           |124 |B002|
```

The data that should end up in column A can be variable up to 11 characters.
The data that should end up in column B can be a variable numeric value up to 3 characters.
The data that should end up in column C can be variable up to 4 characters.

There will always be `[]` around the numbers and there will always be a `*` in between them.

Comment: Seems like a simple enough task. what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

Create and populate sample table (**Please** save us this step in your future questions)

```
DECLARE @t AS TABLE
(
    col  varchar(50) 
)

INSERT INTO @T VALUES
('[1 * B018]'),
('GARAGE'),
('BACK GARDEN. [124 * B002]'),
('[1 * B018]'),
(''),
('[124 * B002]'),
('[1 * B018]'),           
(''),
('[124 * B002]')
```

The query:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN charindex('[', col) > 0 THEN
           LEFT(col, charindex('[', col)-1)
       ELSE
           col
       END AS ColA,

       CASE WHEN charindex('[', col) = 0 THEN
           ''
       ELSE
           SUBSTRING(col, charindex('[', col) +1 ,charindex('*', col) - charindex('[', col) - 1)
       END AS ColB,

       CASE WHEN charindex('[', col) = 0 THEN
           ''
       ELSE
           SUBSTRING(col, charindex('*', col) +1 ,charindex(']', col) - charindex('*', col) - 1)
       END AS ColC
FROM @T
```

Results:

```
ColA            ColB    ColC
                1       B018
GARAGE      
BACK GARDEN.    124     B002
                1       B018

                124     B002
                1       B018

                124     B002
```

Comment: This is great. Should have mentioned that this was a sample set of data, is there any way of extracting data from the whole column into a temporary table in the way you have indicated above? If not I can add the fields to the temporary table query.

Comment: You could use `select into #tmp` to populate a temporary table.

Answer (score 0):

This solution uses CROSS APPLY to make the CHARINDEX  easier to manage.

```
SELECT
    LEFT(SUBSTRING(col,1,CASE WHEN a= 0 THEN LEN(col) ELSE a-1 END),11) AS [ColA]
    ,REPLACE(SUBSTRING(col,a+1,b-a),'*','') AS [ColB]
    ,REPLACE(SUBSTRING(col,b+1,c-b),']','') AS [ColC]
FROM
    @t 
        CROSS APPLY( SELECT CHARINDEX('[',Col,0)A
                            ,CHARINDEX('*',Col,0)B
                            ,CHARINDEX(']',Col,0)C
                            ) Z
```

Note: the examples you have so far -including this one - currently have leading and trailing spaces that will need trimming out with RTRIM & LTRIM. But right now they would cloud the code.